# Javascript Cannot close the window which script has created using window.open

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am working on a script which opens a window with a url and then closes it using window.close(), but then Firefox gives error `Scripts may not close windows that were opened by script`. 
However in my case, the window is really created by the script, so I tried to get the handle of the window in a variable like this: 
`var popup = window.open(url, '', '');`

but now I am getting `null` reference in `popup` variable.

this is insane, because if it returns null then how can a script close the popup which it has opened.

Please help... Thanks in advance.

Comment: `a = window.open('https://google.com', '', ''); setTimeout(() => a.close(), 2000)` worked for me.

Comment: are both the popup variables in the same execution context? i.e is the scope in same space or internal space?

Comment: the execution context is same

Comment: @RolandStarke :( not working, still `null`

Comment: I tried creating a new html file with two buttons `Open Popup` and `Close`, somehow it works there

Comment: but the script in which I am having problem involves angular as well. there is a method invoked on `Connect` button and that's the context where I'm getting `null` in return of `window.open`

Comment: @AbdulFatah i got null the first time when popups where still disallowed. (I allowed them and then it worked.)